# Select all elements between two specific elements

Tags: jquery

I need to select all `a` tags from `<a class="self">` to `<a class="next">`. Here is example

```
<span class="pages">
    <a class="prev">&nbsp;</a>
    <a>13</a>
    <a>14</a>
    <a>15</a>
    <a>16</a>
    <a class="self">17</a>
    <a>18</a>
    <a>19</a>
    <a>20</a>
    <a>21</a>
    <a class="next">&nbsp;</a>
</span>
```

There are `href`s attributes. I don't want to get anything before class `self`. I want everything from `self` to end of the `span` element.

Comment: When you say "I need to to get", what do you mean by "get"? Do you want to remove all other tags, or do you want a jQuery selector that selects the `a.self` to `a.next` elements?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`nextUntil` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) would get all `a` elements between `a.self` and `a.next`, excluding them:

```
$('a.self').nextUntil('a.next', 'a');
```

If you want to include them, just use [`.nextAll` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/):

```
$('a.self').nextAll('a').andSelf();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps someone; it's inclusive, meaning it will send the last element, and the one that's calling the method.

```
/**
 * jQuery.fn.getRangeElements
 * 
 * @access public
 * @parma  HTMLElement|jQuery element
 * @return Array
 */
jQuery.fn.getRangeElements = function(element) {
    var $element = jQuery(element);
    if (jQuery.inArray(element[0], this.siblings()) === -1) {
        return [];
    }
    var $prevAll = this.prevAll();
    if (jQuery.inArray(element[0], $prevAll) !== -1) {
        var $prevUntil = this.prevUntil($element),
            set = [];
        $prevUntil.each(function(index, element) {
            set.push($(element));
        });
        set.unshift(this);
        set.push($element);
        return $(set);
    }
    var $nextUntil = this.nextUntil($element),
        set = [];
    $nextUntil.each(function(index, element) {
        set.push($(element));
    });
    set.unshift(this);
    set.push($element);
    return $(set);
};
```